# How to tell .htaccess to only allow requests to index.php and app/dist/* folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

This is the current folder:

```
/app
  /dist
    /index.html
    /index.css
    /index.js
  /src
    /configurations.json
/index.php
/configurations.php
```

I have sensitive data everywhere:

- `app/src/...`
- `/...`

I want the users to only be able to access to:

- `index.php`
- `app/dist/whateverfile.whateverformat`

The `dist` folder can change, so I have to let them access this directory statically, so I do not have to list every single file.

How is this suposed to be done with this `.htaccess` syntax?

I have this configuration, that lets me access the `index.php`. But no clue to achieve it for the `dist` folder...

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<FilesMatch ".*">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

<Files index.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>

<Files "">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The `dist` folder can change" - I assume you mean the _contents_ of the `dist` folder can change. The `dist` folder itself does not change. (?)

Comment: Are your users accessing the URL `/index.php`, or simply `/` (and using mod_dir to serve the `DirectoryIndex`, ie. `index.php`)?

Answer (score 2):

The `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` directives only target *files*, not directories. If you have access to the server config then you'd perhaps use a `<Directory>` container.

#### Using mod_rewrite

In `.htaccess` you can use mod_rewrite to restrict access to anything other than `/index.php` or `/app/dist/`.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^(index\.php$|app/dist/) - [F]
```

The above will respond with a 403 Forbidden for any request that is not `/index.php` or does not start `/app/dist/`. If you wish to return a 404 instead then change `F` to `R=404`.

The `!` prefix on the regex negates the regex. Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.

If you only want to respond with a 403 for requests that would map to actual files or directories (and 404 otherwise) then add a couple of conditions that check the filesystem (but note that filesystem checks are relatively expensive, so unless you need them, don't use them). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !^(index\.php$|app/dist/) - [F]
```

Only if the requested URL is not in the allowed "group" *and* maps to a file or directory is the `RewriteRule` directive actioned.

However, I would assume your URLs don't actually contain `index.php` (do they?), in which case the user requests `/` and mod_dir issues an internal subrequest for `/index.php` (the `DirectoryIndex`). In which case, you'll need to make the `index.php` optional.

For example:

```
RewriteRule !^((index\.php)?$|app/dist/) - [F]
```

---

#### Using an Apache Expression

Alternatively, you can do this with an Apache expression (Apache 2.4)

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/((index\.php)?$|app/dist/)#">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

The above responds with a 403 for any URL request that is not `/`, `/index.php` or start with `/app/dist/`.

Note that `Order`, `Allow`, `Deny`, etc. are older Apache 2.2 directives and are officially deprecated on Apache 2.4.

---

#### Using mod_setenvif

Another alternative is to use mod_setenvif and set an environment variable if one of the permitted URL-paths is requested and only permit access if this env var is set.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/((index\.php)?$|app/dist/)" ALLOWED
Require env ALLOWED
```

The above sets the `ALLOWED` env var if the any of the permitted URL-paths are requested. The `Require` directive then requires this env var to be set to grant access, otherwise a 403 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your main problem: *"I have sensitive data everywhere"*

That is solved the easiest and most reliably by moving that  sensitive to somewhere outside of your web root...

Consider a web root (your `DocumentRoot`) that only contains the `index.php`
When there is no other data in there you don't need any complex rules to protect it either...

---

You can then use for instance the [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive (in preferably your main server configuration file, or if you prefer a `.htaccess` file in your web root) or mod_rewrite rules to map URI's to documents stored in directories outside of  your DocumentRoot directories/files to specifically allow access.

i.e.

```
.
`-- some-path
    |-- app
    |   `-- dist
    |       |-- index.css
    |       |-- index.html
    |       `-- index.js
    |-- src
    |   `-- configurations.json
    `-- www.example.com
        |-- .htaccess
        `-- index.php
```

Where your main apache configuration defines `/some-path/www.example.com` as the `DocumentRoot` for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
The `.htaccess` can then be something such as this exposes the /some-path/app/ directory and all its contents as the URI path `http://www.example.com/app/`

```
# /some-path/www.example.com/.htaccess
# exposes/some-path/app/ directory  as the URI path `http://www.example.com/app/`

Alias "/app" "/some-path/app"
```

Or be more specific with `Alias "/app/dist" "/some-path/app/dist"` or creative with a regex in an `AlaisMatch` directive.

Comment: Good point about moving "sensitive data" out of the public HTML space, however, you can't use `Alias` directives in `.htaccess` as you suggest. And even using mod_rewrite (to rewrite to areas _outside_ the document root) will require additional server config to at least permit access to the areas being rewritten to (although I have doubts whether this is even possible in `.htaccess`?).

Answer (score 0):

This is how:

```
Options -Indexes
ServerSignature Off 
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ui(/)?$ app/dist/index.html [QSA,END,NC,L]
RewriteRule ui/(.*) app/dist/$1 [QSA,END,NC,L]
RewriteRule !(ui/.*) index.php [QSA,END,NC,L]
```

Notice the `END` flag after every match. This flag is required to simulate the typical `if-else` syntax. But it is not documented on the official docs.

I moved to Node.js finally.